# Placing a Sprite on an Isometric map and detect if a sprite/object is already present - Swift 2

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, isometric

I are building a tower defense game with an isometric map. I am able to build the map and place walls on the map with a 2D array as such:

```
    let wallData = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Where 1-3 are different walls and 0 is grass. You should be able to put towers on the grass (i.e. 0) but not on the walls.

In touchesMoved the tower will move from a selection menu and placed on the grid with touchesEnded. That works fine.

In touchesEnded I am using a for loop to loop through all the nodes in the 2D array.

```
    for x in 0..<wallData.count {
    for y in 0..<wallData[x].count {
    if wallData[x][y] != 0 {
    let coordinate = tilemap?.position(tilemap.pointForPosition(tilemapPosition))
    tower.removeFromParent()
    createTower(coordinate!, withSprite: tower, name: tower.name!)
    }
```

This code still puts the towers anywhere I want on the map.